# How to call stop scripts on BusyBox shutdown?

Tags: init, shutdown, busybox, system-shutdown

I'm running BusyBox with an entry in /etc/inittab

```
::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS
```

The rcS script calls all the start scripts in /etc/rc.d/ on startup.

How is it possible to tell the BusyBox init to shut down all services probably by calling /etc/rc.d/xxx stop on calling the BusyBox applets "poweroff", "halt" or "reboot"?

Answer (score 6):

Just for the records - I finally came along with adding my own shutdown script to /etc/inittab

```
::shutdown:/etc/init.d/rcD
```

The script just loops the startup scripts backwards:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -d /etc/rc.d ]; then                                        
    for x in $(ls -r /etc/rc.d/) ; do                               
        /etc/rc.d/$x stop                                       
    done                                                         
fi
```