Python: Detect system reboot, before SIGKILL?
I have a python script (extension for a system) that collects data and in order to minimize disk-io  only persists the data every 10 minutes.
I've implemented the proper logic to handle all kind of "gracefull" shutdowns I could imagine, but still, when the system reboots, loosing some data.
So, i've checked why:
The devs of that system have an own script which starts all extension scripts. And in case they recive a SIGTERM, they just invoke a SIGKILL on every extension script :-(
(Guess they say "people don't implement SIGTERM any way, make sure it stops right now)
So, is there a way I could detect the invocation of a system reboot, BEFORE some other script sends a SIGKILL to my script? ;)
(Beside local data persisting, I would like to gracefully disconnect from some 3rd party services before shutdown, cause some of them have a quite long timeout period, causing issues right after the reboot.)

What's the init system you're using? systemd, upstart, sysv?

Short answer is no, the SIGKILL signal cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored in Python.  If you get any say in it, try to get your sysadmin to push a SIGTERM first then a SIGKILL after a few seconds.  This is default behavior in tools like kubernetes, where the time between a SIGTERM and the final SIGKILL is 10 seconds.

@NickODell it's a "BusyBox", dunno on what that is build.

@VoNWooDSoN - yeah, I know that, so I would like to know if there is a "reboot" (followed by a SIGKILL through another process receiving a SIGTERM) incoming, and try if that is enough time to clean up ;)

One simple idea would be to write each new piece of data to a file, and flush it. That will still be buffered at the OS level. Then, you would be relying on the OS to flush its buffers on shutdown to persist the data.

@dognose That's probably busybox init, then. There's a way to ask busybox to run a script on shutdown. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031839/how-to-call-stop-scripts-on-busybox-shutdown If you run a shutdown script before the other shutdown script is run, you can persist the data before you receive SIGKILL.

@NickODell The shutdown script sounds interesting - it could basically just send a proper SIGTERM to my actual script. Depends on the order of things ofc (Shutdown scripts before ending other scripts?). will try it out.

No, The answer is no. Without any other context about how the software is being run there is no reboot signal sent to processes on a shutdown or reboot.  If you know the answer to Nick ODell's first question, there may be hope.  systemd, upstart, etc.. can be configured to relay shut-down messages.  I'd definitely recommend that, if you can, wrap up your script in a systemd wrapper to handle graceful shutdown and initialization ( and enable if your script is "always on").  Check out this tutorial it's pretty good.
